# Geometry nodes - Trim Curves with different values

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've created geometry containing of 3 overlapping circles (pic 1, pic2), and rotated each circle 120deg on Z axis (pic2). Then I've generated a mesh line of 2 points, and instanced my previously generated geometry on these points with different scales. Then I've converted everything back to curves and trimmed curves and converted to mesh with a profile (pic3).

But I want the gaps between segments to be the same. So I do need to trim circles with different values. I can calculate needed trim values, but as I understand, the "Curve Trim" node trims all splines in geometry with the same value? Is there no way to do, what do I need?

Thanx

P.S. The wanted result is on the last screenshot.

P.P.S. The right side of the third screenshot is all about calculating the trim length. I can place the attribute with the right value in every point, that is placed on the corresponding spline, but that does not bring anything...

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

[image: current result]

[image: wanted result]

[image: wanted result]

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like this: (it's for sure not the most elegant solution, but it works)

I have used two different geometry node objects:

[image]

[image]

[image]
result:

[image]

Comment: Nice. But the problem is, I'll need several hundreds of these "circles", placed in a special way on other object. I've ommited this part to make my node setup easier to understand. And placing every geometry manually... sure, it's possible, but it goes against the whole idea of geometry nodes, I think )

Comment: so why can't you just instance the result of my setup (or "one" circle) with point instance? might be i don't really understand your question....

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the first post, how it should look at the end. There are just scaled cubes used as instances on that screenshot. I'm trying to replace them with splines to make them curved corresponding to the circles radius.

Comment: That screenshot helped a lot to understand!!! Thank you

Comment: I am not on my computer right now but it should be pretty easy to create a mesh line with GN and point instance my nodegroup and change Radius by an attribute

Comment: Yes, that can work. Will try it out in several hours

Comment: Is there _any_ way of getting at the geometry of instances or are their meshes fixed? Or _any_ way (other than multi-branch trees) of generating multiples, which you can manipulate after generation? Racking my brains.. maybe missing something...

Comment: @RobinBetts : I am not sure what you want to know?

Comment: @Chris, sorry, not clear. I would love, somehow, inside gnodes, to make multiples of, say, the arc-of-circle, and still be able to manipulate them, per element.

Comment: I would love that too…but I have no idea how…

Comment: I've tried it out, but the problem renains. Even if I chreate separate object with it's own geonodes for the arc, I still can not set their curve trim parameter individually, but have to create hundreds of arcs manually. Or am I missing something? The ability to manipulate objects modifiers inside of nodes would help...

Comment: does it have to be GN or can it be animation nodes too?

Comment: Actually it does not have to be anything ) I've just wanted to spend some time with GN to learn it. And at the poit was interested, if there a way to realize my idea. Seems, that there is no, at the moment. Will wait for new nodes to be added. I'm sure, loop nodes will be added at some point. It will help a lot. And we do really need point indexes )

Comment: It IS possible - already now - I am pretty sure - give me a bit time…. but I totally agree with u: loops would be great

Comment: i now made it with pure GN something like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYVUv.jpg but i don't know whether this is ok for you as anwser...and changing some parameters it looks like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d94lN.jpg

Comment: But the segments look straight, not curved? I've added another image for explanation, what I'm trying to achive. [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa3iB.jpg And btw, every segment should have endpoints, as I need to attach other objects at that points... )

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this will be solved in the future. There is a new node for that which will soon be published

Comment: As I've told before, it is a fan project, so I'll wait for new nodes ) Thank you Chris for your time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I fell in love with GN as well 